# COM: how to specify a specific type of COM object as an argument in idl

Tags: c++, com, idl

Currently I have some code that looks like this

```
void calc_run(Calculation *c, Input *i);

STDMETHODIMP CCalculation::run(IUnknown* input)
{
    calc_run(calc,((CMyInputClass*)input)->get_input());  
    return S_OK;
}
```

In other words `CCalculation::run` wants a pointer to a `CMyInputClass`, but currently it takes `IUnknown` and downcasts.

Presumably this is bad.

But how can I specify more precisely to COM which object I want?  I tried changing the `.c`, `.h` and `.idl` files but the compiler doesn't recognise `CMyInputClass*` as a type specification in the `idl`.

```
interface ICalculation : IDispatch{
[id(2), helpstring("method run")] HRESULT run([in] CMyInputClass* input);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COM way would be to introduce a COM interface that `CMyInputClass` would implement and use that interface in `run()` declaration:

```
interface ICalculationInput : IUnknown {
     //some methods here
};

interface ICalculation : IDispatch{
     [id(2), helpstring("method run")] HRESULT run([in] ICalculationInput* input);
};
```